# Access namespace not defined exactly in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces

Lets assume my XAML is defined as below with my imported namespace in mycontrols.

```
<Grid x:Class="LayoutGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"         
    xmlns:mycontrols="clr-namespace:Predefined.Controls;assembly=UIControls"  
    >
```

If i was to use something defined in the namespace `Predefined.Controls` then i would simply reference it with its alias `mycontrols`

Example:

```
<mycontrols:MyCustomButton Name="SubmitButton" />
```

Now if the namespace `Predefined.Controls.CustomTextBoxes` also existed, is there a way to use a control inside this namespace without having to add it to the XAML definition at the top?

Something like this??

```
<mycontrols.CustomTextBoxes:MyCustomTextBox Name="TextBox1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In XML, the namespace prefix defines the namespace, you can't just tack things onto it.  You'll need to add the full CLR namespace as an XML namespace declaration in a parent element:

```
xmlns:ctb="clr-namespace:Predefined.Controls.CustomTextBoxes;assembly=UIControls"
```

And use that prefix in when you instantiate that element/control in your XAML:

```
<ctb:MyCustomTextBox />
```